# how to pass javascript value to viewbag value

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewbag

I would to ask, is it possible to pass a javascript value to a viewbag? I have tried to serach on stakoverflow, it seems that it is possible to pass viewbag value to javasript, but not vice versa.
Thank you very much

Comment: `ViewBag` is server side code. You can not unless you make an ajax call to set a value in the controller, but that makes no sense for `ViewBag` What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: ViewBag is server side variable.you can't do so using javascript.
what you want to achieve actually? do you need pass value client side to server side?if it is then you can do it in a various way.

Answer (score 1):

Your Server end :

```
 ViewBag.Js = "alert()";
```

Your CsHtml Page :

```
<script type='text/Javascript'>    
  @Html.Raw(@ViewBag.Js);
</script>;
```